# Is it possible to set persistent duration for notifications until I close them manually in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: notification

Is any way in Ubuntu 18 to show desktop notifications until I close them manually?

Comment: No there isn't. Maybe possible in other desktop environments.

Comment: Notifications are intended for rather low-priority information like volume changes. They are not-persistent by design for that reason. If you need persistence in one application, then that application might be misusing notifications. There are persistent alternatives like AppIndicators and Dialog boxes and Logging and others available. File a bug against that application to let the developers know that notifications are not meeting your need.

Comment: Will https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-notifications.html.en help in case what you actually want is to see missed notifications?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread but you can use `notify-send -u critical "ADD MESSAGE HERE"`, it sets the message urgency to critical which keeps it visible until you give it some attention.